# How To Convert Values Into Sha-1 And Base64 In Javascript

Tags: javascript, base64, sha

I want to convert these values into Sha-1 and after that I want to convert again into base64. I tried lots of methods. But , none of them work.

```
var nonce = 5;
var unixtm = 6;
var pw = '123';
var shapw = nonce+ ' + ' +unixtm+ ' + ' +pw; //5 + 6 + 123
```

I mean , First of all I want to convert 'shapw' into Sha-1 and after that convert into Base64. Here is the formula -

> FinalPw = Base64 ( SHA-1 ( nonce + created + SHA-1 ( password ) ) )

How can I do this ??

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of libraries which could help you to create SHA1 hash. Here for example https://github.com/emn178/js-sha1. Install it and use like

```
sha1('Message to hash');
var hash = sha1.create();
hash.update('Message to hash');
hash.hex();
```

For base64 there are `btoa()` (to base64) and `atob()` (from base64) functions.

Comment: It gives me this error - Uncaught ReferenceError: sha1 is not defined. How can I Fix this ?? I Insatlled Js-Sha1 using nodeJs.